# Python string regular expression

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-2.x

I need to do a string compare to see if 2 strings are equal, like:

```
>>> x = 'a1h3c'
>>> x == 'a__c'
>>> True
```

independent of the 3 characters in middle of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use anchors.

```
>>> import re
>>> x = 'a1h3c'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^a.*c$')
>>> pattern.match(x) != None
True
```

This would check for the first and last char to be `a` and `c` . And it won't care about the chars present at the middle.

If you want to check for exactly three chars to be present at the middle then you could use this,

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^a...c$')
>>> pattern.match(x) != None
True
```

Note that end of the line anchor `$` is important , without `$`, `a...c` would match `afoocbarbuz`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if str1[0] == str2[0]:
    # do something.
```

You can repeat this statement as many times as you like.

This is slicing. We're getting the first value. To get the last value, use `[-1]`.

I'll also mention, that with slicing, the string can be of any size, as long as you know the relative position from the beginning or the end of the string.

Comment: I believe op was looking for an answer involving regex

Comment: @AndrewGrant what makes you think that?

Comment: "Python string regular expression"

Comment: @AndrewGrant If they needed regex or anything, they could've said it upfront. And please don't go around attempting to modify others' answers. Play the game fairly, and don't accuse myself of providing a *solution that does not solve the problem*.

Comment: This is not slicing. This is simple indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be solved with string indexing, but if you want an intro to regex, here ya go.

```
import re
your_match_object = re.match(pattern,string)
```

the pattern in your case would be

```
pattern = re.compile("a...c") # the dot denotes any char but a newline
```

from here, you can see if your string fits this pattern with

```
print pattern.match("a1h3c") != None
```

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match